# Получить файл в приложении (Smack)

Tags: java, android, xmpp

Я использую `Smack` и `xmpp` для отправки сообщений в приложении, возник вопрос, как правильно получить файл в приложении.

Я использую такой файл трансфер листенер для получения файлов в приложении:

```
manager.addFileTransferListener
(new FileTransferListener() {
         public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest request) {
                                   new Thread() {
                                        @Override
                                   public void run() {
                IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
                File mf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File file = new File(mf.getAbsoluteFile() + "/DCIM/Camera/" + transfer.getFileName());
               try {
                   transfer.recieveFile(file);
                   while (!transfer.isDone()) {
                     try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
} catch (Exception e) {                                                                                 Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());                                                                                }                                                                                if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)) {                                                                                    Log.e("ERROR!!! ", transfer.getError() + "");                                                                                }                                                                                if (transfer.getException() != null) {                                                                                    transfer.getException().printStackTrace();                                                                                }                                                                            }                                                                       
Log.e("", e.getMessage());                                                                          
}
                                                                        }
                                                                    }.start();

}
```

});

Я использую сервер `OpenFire`, а так же я скачала клиент `Psi` для отправки сообщений и тестирования. Когда я пытаюсь отправить файл с `Psi` пользователю, у которого установлено Android приложение на телефоне, `Psi` запрашивает `request` перед отправкой файла, `и когда я проверяю в дебаггере, то программа не заходит в строчку кода`IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
Как принять этот `request` на телефоне программно? Что не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашла решения, для того, что бы принять файл на другом девайсе нужно использовать FileTransferListener, пример кода:

```
 public class FileTransferIMPL implements FileTransferListener {

        @Override
        public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest request) {

            final IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
            try {
                InputStream is = transfer.recieveFile();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyXMPP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

При получении connection установите

```
Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
```

Comment: попробовала, но файл все равно не передается.